# Xamarin Form: ListView causing Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index

Tags: ios, xamarin, viewmodel, indexoutofboundsexception

I have tried a lot of combination to test the code in `LoadData` function.

The first time the Page loaded, the `LoadData` function got called. Later user change the date which causing the `LoadData` function to be called again. This time there was an error quoted below. If I commented the Collection = programs line, the code have no problem.

The problem even if the programs has 0 item in the second execution of the function.

```
public async Task LoadData (DateTime day)
        { 
            this.day = day;

            var programs = await new ECEProgramLogic().GetGrouppedProgram(day.Date, actionNameType);

            Collection = programs; 
        }

    private ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel<object>> collection;
        public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel<object>> Collection 
        {
            get
            {
                return collection;
            }
            set
            {
                collection = value;
                Banner = new NoDataBannerViewModel<GroupViewModel<object>>(value, AppResources.NoDataToShow);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Collection));
            }
        }
```

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: index

Stacktrace from Xamarin:

> at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.get_Item (System.Int32 index) [0x0000b] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ListProxy.cs:127 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.System.Collections.IList.get_Item (System.Int32 index) [0x00000] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ListProxy.cs:444 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].get_Item (System.Int32 index) [0x00008] in <afec569c85894ae9a18371a2fecd2d37>:0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.HeaderViewDisplayingEnded (UIKit.UITableView tableView, UIKit.UIView headerView, System.nint section) [0x0001f] in <82f6100a289642ae988dc0d85a373bef>:0 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend(intptr,intptr)
>     at UIKit.UITableView.ReloadData () [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UITableView.g.cs:792 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer.UpdateItems (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, System.Int32 section, System.Boolean resetWhenGrouped) [0x002b8] in <82f6100a289642ae988dc0d85a373bef>:0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer.OnCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <82f6100a289642ae988dc0d85a373bef>:0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x0000a] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].GroupedReset () [0x000b6] in <afec569c85894ae9a18371a2fecd2d37>:0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnCollectionChangedGrouped (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00459] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnProxyCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, System.Boolean fixWindows) [0x00008] in <afec569c85894ae9a18371a2fecd2d37>:0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnProxyCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnItemsSourceChanged (System.Boolean fromGrouping) [0x00069] in <afec569c85894ae9a18371a2fecd2d37>:0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].BindableOnPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x00020] in :0 
>     at (wrapper delegate-invoke) .invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs(object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
>     at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x0000a] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:146 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x00000] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:401 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00107] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:602 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x0015b] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:399 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore (System.Object sourceObject, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject target, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Boolean fromTarget) [0x001f9] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:172 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply (System.Boolean fromTarget) [0x0003e] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:56 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.b__47_0 () [0x00000] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:557 
>     at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSAction.cs:163 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
>     at Tux.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/simon/Documents/AimyPlus/EceAdmin/Tux/Tux.iOS/Main.cs:17

```
> Xamarin.Android
Version: 8.2.0.16 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/simon/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        6.0 (API level 23)
        7.1 (API level 25)
        8.0 (API level 26)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.5
SDK Platform Tools Version: 25.0.5
SDK Build Tools Version: 25.0.3

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Xamarin Inspector
Version: 1.4.0
Hash: b3f92f9
Branch: master
Build date: Fri, 19 Jan 2018 22:00:34 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 9.2 (13772)
Build 9C40b

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 4.2.1.28 (Visual Studio Community)

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 11.9.1.24 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: f62de472
Branch: xcode9.3
Build date: 2018-03-29 19:30:53-0400
```

Comment: try change the name of property `Collection` to another name maybe there is a confusion between `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection` and you property name

Comment: I tried change Collection to Collectionff but still having the problem....

Comment: what's the difference !  try change it to `CollectionData` or something like this .

Comment: Sorry my f key not work that well

Comment: can you specify the Xamarin venison that you work on

Comment: I have added the info on top

Comment: What is the type of `program`?

Comment: The programs just a GroupViewModel with grouped programs of data. I realised, if I append new data without clearing it. Everything goes fine. But when clear it and add new data in. The error start to show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an issue of the updated Xamarin.Forms 2.51444934. It happened when doing a groupped listview. In order to solve:

```
ListView.HasUnevenRows = false;
ListView.IsGroupingEnabled = false;
((ObservableCollection<T>)listView.ItemsSource).Clear();
ListView.HasUnevenRows = true;
ListView.IsGroupingEnabled = true;
```

Put similar code before replacing new data collection. The problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks, this solved this issue for me. I was changing BindingContexts and didn't need to clear the list views, just had to set values to false before changing context then to true after changing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding those lines to listview properties works for me.

IsGroupingEnabled="false"
CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"